# Clone the git repo (.git directory) into an existing "working" directory (not tracked)

Tags: backup, git

I did a backup of my “Code“ folder while switching computers and my (custom) backup tool didn’t copy `.git` folders. So I have folders with an (usually) up-to-date working directory, but that aren’t tracked by git in any way.

For repos that have been pushed to a remote, can I “clone“ just the `.git` directory and transform my folders into actual local git repos?

What I tried already:

- `git init` then adding the remote, `fetch`ing and trying to merge or rebase in various ways (the new repo is empty so doesn’t even have a single commit)
- `git clone --bare ...` into another folder, then renaming that folder to `.git`. `git` doesn’t consider the working directory to even be a git repo.

Comment: It actually isn’t that much of a problem since cloning the whole repo doesn’t take much time. But still, if there’s an obvious or not so obvious solution to this, I’m curious to learn about it!

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach for this situation:

- clone the repo into a fresh folder `foobar`, ensuring I have checked out the proper branch
- delete everything except the `.git` folder
- copy the existing files into the `foobar` folder

If you're not checking out the proper branch before replacing the repo content, you can still select the branch using `git reset` commands.